# I expected the loop to copy null character or something but it copies the char from the beginning again. Why is that? How does this loop work?

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops

I am trying to check whether a char array in loop copies the character from other char array which has characters lesser then the number of loop iteration

```
#include <stdio.h>[enter image description here][1]
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int c=0;
    char a[10],x[5]="hamme";
while(c<10)
    {
        a[c]=x[c];
    c++;
    }
    printf("%s",a);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Try `x[6]` instead so there's space for the null terminator. Of course it's still going to be undefined behavior until you make it have a size of at least `10`.

Comment: Also, have a look at the `memcpy` function in `<string.h>`, which was designed for this very purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x[5]="hamme"`

Creates a character array of `5` characters, not a **string** with `"hamme"` which would require `6` characters to store (recall you need storage for the *nul-character* at the end)

When looping `while(c<10)` you invoke *Undefined Behavior* by reading past the end (beyond the array bounds) of `x`.

Your "sometimes it copies sometimes it doesn't -- is the result of *Undefined Behavior*.

If you declare `char x[] = "hamme";` then `x` will be initialized to include the *nul-terminating* character and you can simply loop until it has been copied to `a`, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int c = 0;
    char a[10],
        x[] = "hamme";

    do
        a[c] = x[c];
    while (x[c++]);

    printf ("%s\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** you must insure `a` has sufficient storage to hold the string in `x`, otherwise you are back in the *Undefined Behavior* boat.)

To ensure that does not happen, you can include `string.h` and compare the length of `x` (*plus* `1`) to the storage available in `a[]` and only copy if it is sufficient, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    size_t c = 0;
    char a[10],
        x[] = "hamme";

    if (strlen (x) + 1 > sizeof a) {
        fputs ("error, length of x exceeds storage in a.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    do
        a[c] = x[c];
    while (x[c++]);

    printf ("%s\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note** the change in type for `c` from `int` to `size_t` to avoid a comparison between signed and unsigned values in `if (strlen (x) + 1 > sizeof a)`)

Answer (score 0):

C allows direct memory access to your program, when we try to assign anything more than the index in could be anything. Can cause unexpected bug. This should not be happen. An array is nothing but a pointer to a memory location. In other words, **some_array [i]** is same as ***(some_array + i)** and also **some_array[i]** is also same as **i [ some_array ]** !